# Azure Notification Hub with Cordova app(iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to use Notification Hub to push Cordova app(iOS)

Azure side is as below.

[image: Notification Hub]

[image: Notification Hub]

Source code on client side is as below.
I'm sure Azure client is correctly connected and registration is successful.

```
    function initPushNotification(){
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            android: {
                senderID: "12345679"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: "true",
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
        });

        var registrationSuccess = function () {
            alert('Registered with Azure!');
        };

        var registrationFailure = function (error) {
            alert('Failed registering with Azure: ' + error);
        };

        push.on('registration', function(data) {
            client.push.apns.registerTemplate(handle,
            'myTemplate', template, null)
            .done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
        });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            alert('Push Received: ' + data.message);
        });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        });
```

But when I execute Test Send from notification hub page, nothing happens.
I tried from simple ruby script to APNS directly and notification comes to iPhone correctly.

[image: Notification Hub Test]

Does anyone know how to fix it or any information?

My environment is

- MacBook Pro
- OS X ElCapitan
- Cordova 6.0.0
- com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services 1.2.9 "Windows Azure Mobile Services"
- phonegap-plugin-push 1.6.2 "PushPlugin"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the call to client.push.register() is not succeeding for some reason. I'm not using the particular plugin you're using, I'm using [azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client) combined with [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). So far, this combination is working for my purposes.

You can find a more complete example here: [Add Push Notifications to your Apache Cordova App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/).

One thing I would add is that when you call the push.register() API in the azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client plugin, you can give it an error function callback that gets called if the API call fails. It would look like this:

> push.register('apns', data.registrationId, null, null, function(err)
>   {console.log(err);});

Lastly, in Visual Studio, you can also connect to your notification hub and list and manage the registrations. This is useful to determine if the APNS registration is really accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client does not work for me because server sdk and client sdk versions do not match.

Comment: Did you use notification hub? I could have done without notification hub but my goal is to use notification hub, so I want to use client.push.register(). now I changed to client.push.apns.registerTemplate() and seems registration is successful. but I cannot receive notification test from notification hub test page.

Comment: Yes, I've only used Azure Notification Hubs for my project as it simplifies the management of registered devices. I did see cases where the registration initially succeeds, but is subsequently rejected by GCM. There are a variety of reasons for this, but it may depend on the plugins you're using. If you convert to azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client you may have an easier time as that's more current.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client again.

Comment: your link will work with support of app service . if we want to do with out app service what I have to do ??
I followed this link "https://github.com/projectsphonegapdev1/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub" but its not working